# How To Execute Some Common Steps Before Test Class On Android Espresso Test?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test one app with espresso on android, I want to test some cases after sign in. How can I execute the cases with only sign in once with espresso?

Comment: You can mock your sign in state in `ActivityTestRule` as it runs before the `@Before` tag

Comment: Codes in ActivityTestRule cannot touch the UI element. Is there any other idea?